# How to assign scope variable with comprehension expression to ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a a set of data `items`:

```
$scope.items = [
    {
        "value": 1,
        "text": "1st"
    },
    {
        "value": 2,
        "text": "2nd"
    }
]
```

and I want to be able to create a select tag like:

```
<select ng-model="currentSelection" ng-options="item.value as item.text for item in items"></select>
```

This is the normal way of displaying a dropdown with all the `items`.

Is it possible to assign `"item for item in items"` as a scope variable and assign that scope variable to `ng-options`? IE (in controller):

```
$scope.options = "item.value as item.text for item in items";
```

And in view:

```
<select ng-model="currentSelection" ng-options="{{options}}"></select>
```

Right now, my implementation of the last example results in options being loaded as an empty string and the only reason I can think of is that scope variables are being loaded after ng attributes/variables are loaded first.

Comment: what version of angularjs are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/U3pVM/28539/)

```
var app =angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope){
$scope.currentSelection = "";
$scope.expression = "item.value as item.text for item in items";
$scope.items = [
    {
        "value": 1,
        "text": "1st"
    },
    {
        "value": 2,
        "text": "2nd"
    }
]
});
```

This should work.  Other way is to create a directive.